# Login on and android app with password stored in DB hashed with PHP Password Hashing

Tags: php, android, mysql, security, hash

I'm using PHP 5.5 Password Hashing to manage the login in my web application.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php

Our passwords are stored in our database hashed using PHP password hashing. When a user wants to login we compare the hashed password from the database with the one typed by the user using `password_verify`.

I want to expand the application to allow login from an Android application.

The solution I have found is to call a PHP process using POST and send the password and user name to it. This process will answer with 0 or 1 indicating whether the login information matches a stored username / password pair or not.

**Question:**

Is the approach above the best approach?

Comment: Please remember to use https when sending plain text passwords over the net :)

Comment: Yes! ;) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible...

Recommended:

> > It is always better and safe to develop an **API** in server
> >     using **REST** (now for login ) so that you can expand the
> >     functionality in future.
>
> **Additional** : You might need to pass a **token or current session id** from server to app along with other data once you created the session. Bcoz when you need to
>   store data in sessions in server then the app should pass the session
>   id in every request to server to get those details from session. Because the server
>   cannot identify the session id (PHPSESSID) of the incoming request
>   from Android app. (But possible when the request from browser)
>
> Otherwise you have to use DB to store session Details.